# Whirlwind/tornado/dust devil in the middle of nowhere

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air, atmospheric-science, flow, vortex

I live in area which have many properties similar to desert. Many times when I drive by I see a whirlwind/tornado/dust devil of sand or other garbage parts.
I would like to ask how this was normally being created and what kind of force keeps it stable?
How high can such a vortex can get to? (Just an estimation) Is it something unique to desert landscape or this is happening all over the earth surface?

Comment: By "turbulence" do you mean whirlwind/tornado/[dust devil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_devil)?

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Dust devil is exactly what I looked for (I didn't heard this name before).

Comment: @ChrisWhite the wiki link completely answers this question so why don't you answer it by copying the relevant description so that the question does not remain unanswered?

Comment: @annav To be honest I actually didn't read the wiki page. I have to go now, so if you or anyone else wants to make an answer, feel free :)

Comment: I think it will be better to delete this question (for some reasons the delete button doesn't work for me). The Wiki entry is enough for my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [Wikipedia page on Dust Devils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_devil) explains it quite well:

> Dust devils form when hot air near the surface rises quickly through a
>   small pocket of cooler, low- pressure air above it. If conditions are
>   just right, the air may begin to rotate. As the air rapidly rises, the
>   column of hot air is stretched vertically, thereby moving mass closer
>   to the axis of rotation, which causes intensification of the spinning
>   effect by conservation of angular momentum. The secondary flow in the
>   dust devil causes other hot air to speed horizontally inward to the
>   bottom of the newly forming vortex. As more hot air rushes in toward
>   the developing vortex to replace the air that is rising, the spinning
>   effect becomes further intensified and self-sustaining. A dust devil,
>   fully formed, is a funnel-like chimney through which hot air moves,
>   both upwards and in a circle. As the hot air rises, it cools, loses
>   its buoyancy and eventually ceases to rise. As it rises, it displaces
>   air which descends outside the core of the vortex. This cool air
>   returning acts as a balance against the spinning hot-air outer wall
>   and keeps the system stable.
>
> The spinning effect, along with surface friction, usually will produce
>   a forward momentum. The dust devil is able to sustain itself longer by
>   moving over nearby sources of hot surface air.
>
> As available extreme hot air near the surface is channeled up the dust
>   devil, eventually surrounding cooler air will be sucked in. Once this
>   occurs, the effect is dramatic, and the dust devil dissipates in
>   seconds. Usually this occurs when the dust devil is not moving fast
>   enough (depletion) or begins to enter a terrain where the surface
>   temperatures are cooler, causing unbalance.